# How to disable the click option or selecting the row in a table in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, click

I am new to iphone development.I am displaying a xml parsed contents in a grouped tableView.I want disable the click event on it(i should not be able to click it at all) .Since it is grouped table , it contains two tables and i want to disable the first table only and not the second table.How can i achieve it?Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the user to be able to click on a table view, just use this code:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , its working.Since it is grouped table , it contains two tables and i want to disable the first table only and not the second table.How can i do that?

Comment: A grouped table is still only one table. Look at the `indexPath` variable which gets passed, it should tell you which section was clicked (along with the row). Put in an if statement to return nil for the section you don't want selected. For the other one, return `indexPath` as is.

Comment: @Warrior then you should ask the question for section not two table.Because one group table have only one table view with many section.

Answer (score 1):

Use Uitable View delegates and data Sources

```
//#endif
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"Returning num sections");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Returning num rows");
    return [copyListOfItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}
```